# skip lines using readLine() - Swift 2.2

Tags: swift, swift2

I was wondering whether I can skip lines when I read an stdin input with several lines using readLine().

e.g. stdin input

```
Hello
World
```

Is it possible to get the second line directly without reading the first or getting the lines by providing a line number?

I'd like to do something similar like:

```
getLine(1) //by line number
```

**Here is my hacky solution**

*example input:*

```
36
3
1 2 3
5
1 2 3 4 5
...
```

*read just every second line (skip first line as well):*

```
var lines = [String]()
var counter = -1
while let line = readLine() {
    counter+=1
    if counter == 2 {
        lines.append(line)
        counter = 0
    }
}
print(lines)
```

Comment: How are you using it currently? Please show relevant code.

Comment: I do:
`let a = readLine() //"Hello"`
`let b = readLine() //"World"`

Comment: So you're using this in a CLI app and you're piping a text file to it, or are you using stdin input? Please give details about your process.

Comment: I'm using stdin input. Sorry for not mentioning. I didn't think that it matters because I named the readLine() function

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a quick and easy function for getting a line at index of a text.

```swift
func getLineOfText(lineIndex: Int, text: String) -> String?{
    let line = text.componentsSeparatedByString("\n")
    if line.count > lineIndex {
         return line[lineIndex]
    }
    else {
         return nil
    }
}
```

Use it like this:

```swift
let text = "Line1 \nLine 2"
getLineOfText(1, text: text) //Returns Optional("Line 2")
```

**Or if you want to use it as ant extension:**

```swift
extension String {
    func getLineAtIndex(index: Int) -> String? {
        let lines = self.componentsSeparatedByString("\n")
        if lines.count > index {
            return lines[index]
        }
        else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

Use like:

```swift
let text = "Line1 \nLine 2"
text.getLineAtIndex(1) // Returns Optional("Line 2")
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you say "I'm using stdin input" and your input has several lines, I'm assuming you're reading a text file with something like this in the terminal:

> $ cat file.txt | myapp

In this case you can read all the file lines with a loop:

```
var lines: [String] = []
while let line = readLine() {
    lines.append(line)
}
print(lines)
```

And you can easily get a line from the resulting array using its index:

```
print(lines[1])
```

---

If you need to get a specific line when the text is sent to your app, use something like this:

```
func input() -> [String] {
    let input = NSFileHandle.fileHandleWithStandardInput()
    let inputData = input.availableData
    if let text = String(data: inputData, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
        return text.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.newlineCharacterSet())
    }
    return []
}

func getLine(index: Int, from lines: [String]) -> String? {
    if lines.count > index {
        return lines[index]
    }
    return nil
}
```

Possible usage:

```
if let line2 = getLine(1, from: input()) {
    print(line2)
}
```

---

You could also read every other line like this:

```
let lines = input()

for (index, line) in lines.enumerate() {
    if index % 2 != 0 {
        print(line)
    }
}
```

Comment: Of course that's a solution, but I tried to avoid to loop through all the lines. I'm currently using a similar solution to yours where I'm having a line counter and where I'm just reading the lines of an specific index. I was just hoping that I can avoid the loop somehow